# Prove $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\geq 1$ when $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(z^2-1)=8^3$

Tags: inequality

Please help to prove this inequality.

Prove $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\geq 1$ when $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(z^2-1)=8^3$ and each of $x,y,z$ is greater than 1.

Thanks.

Comment: This will likely require similar machinery as [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446863/suppose-xyz-8-try-to-prove-that-sqrt-frac11x-sqrt-frac11y-s#comment959579_446863). You are asking about the inequality on the other side, after a simple change of variables. You have the 'near equality' case of $x \rightarrow 1, y, z \rightarrow \infty$ to take care of.

Comment: Not necessarily. The minimum is reached when the $x,y,z$ are equal here.

Answer (score 1):

Write the means
$$
\begin{align}
H &= \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}} \\
G &= \sqrt[3]{xyz} \\
A &=\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
then the power mean (AM-GM-HM) inequality gives $H \le G \le A$. Also note
$$
xy+yz+zx = xyz\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{3G^3}{H}
$$

Now given
$$
\begin{align}
8^3 &= (x^2-1)(y^2-1)(z^2-1) \\
&= (x-1)(y-1)(z-1)(x+1)(y+1)(z+1) \\
&= (xyz-(xy+yz+zx)+(x+y+z)-1)(xyz+(xy+yz+zx)+(x+y+z)+1) \\
&= \left(G^3\left(1-\frac{3}{H}\right)+3A-1\right)
   \left(G^3\left(1+\frac{3}{H}\right)+3A+1\right)
\end{align}
$$
Then we have either
$$
1-\frac{3}{H} < 0 \\
\implies H < 3 \implies
1< \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}
$$
or else
$$
1-\frac{3}{H} \ge 0 \\
\implies G^3(1-3/H) \ge H^3(1-3/H) = H^3-3H^2
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
8^3 &= \left(G^3\left(1-\frac{3}{H}\right)+3A-1\right)
   \left(G^3\left(1+\frac{3}{H}\right)+3A+1\right) \\
&\ge (H^3-3H^2+3H-1)(H^3+3H^2+3H+1) \\
&= (H-1)^3(H+1)^3 \\
&= (H^2-1)^3 \\
\implies H &\le 3 \\
\implies 1 &\le \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: One typo: the quadratic mean is a square root, nota square. Although this doesn't affect your results, it is worth noting. Also am gm would work well intead of Cauchy-shwarz

Comment: Another typo on the final lines: $H \le 3$, Again, this doesnt affect your results

Comment: One last thing that may be critical and went unnoticed: when you change the sign of the inequality you have, you also change it's direction. That does affect and I couldn't find a fast-repair...If I come up with a solution, i will post it here. Meanwhile, that negative sign is doing our lives impossible.

Comment: I agree. The inequality involving $-3G^6/H^2$ in the middle does not hold.

Comment: Substantially rewritten. Is there still a problem?

Comment: Seems not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2-1=\frac{8bc}{a^2}$, $y^2-1=\frac{8ac}{b^2}$ and $z^2-1=\frac{8ab}{c^2}$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Hence, by Holder we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{8bc}{a^2}}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a^2+8bc)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a^2+8bc)}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a^2+8bc)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+8abc)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+8abc)+3\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+8abc)}}\geq1.$$
Done!

Answer (score -1):

By symmetry, the minimum value of the expression

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

under the constraint $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(z^2-1)=8^3$ will occur when $x=y=z$.  From this, it follows that the minimum occurs when $x=y=z=3$, and the minimum is $1$.

Comment: And by symmetry the minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ when $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$ occurs when...

Comment: Simmetry is a good point to start, but it is not a complete proof.